# Rails roo gem and undefined method `open_spreadsheet'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app I'm starting work on where I need to process a csv. I am using Ryan Bates http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel as a guide. I was able to pull down his app from github and experiment. Now I'm trying to create my own. I have all of the base code in place but am getting the error...

```
 NoMethodError in StudentsController#import

undefined method `open_spreadsheet' for #<Class:0x9b7c1f0>

Rails.root: /home/user/railsApps/t4
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/models/student.rb:5:in `import'
app/controllers/students_controller.rb:12:in `import'
```

Here are my controller and model...

## app/controllers/students_controller.rb

```
  def import
    Student.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Students imported."
  end
```

## app/models/student.rb

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      student = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
      student.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
      puts student.inspect
    end
  end
end
```

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Where is the `open_spreadsheet` method defined? It doesn't appear to be defined in your `Student` class, and you haven't included an libraries in this class either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at that Railscasts episode, it appears that he has defined `open_spreadsheet` as a class method in the `Student` class. You don't have an `open_spreadsheet` method defined, and thus Ruby can't find any `open_spreadsheet` method when you try to invoke it.

Define an `open_spreadsheet` method inside your `Student` class and that error should go away.